Tailwind for MUI component overriden
I'm right now moving my application to Tailwind styling, because it is much more comfortable to style right in the HTML.
I'm using quite a lot MUI components and my first question is, if it makes sense move from sx to tailwind for these components. For some of them it already works, but some tailwind styles are overridden somehow. For example for this component the text color is the standard one.
<ListSubheader
  className="h-8 text-green-400"
>

Can you please support me, how to make it work?
in the documentation is mentioned I might need to use slotProps, but I cannot make it work.
<ListSubheader
  className="h-8"
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      className: "text-green-400",
    },
  }}
>


You can make a utility more important by adding the ! character at the beginning.
!text-green-400
 <ListSubheader className="!text-green-400">Hi</ListSubheader>

